# Optimizing thread pool size

Tags: java, optimization, concurrency

In [his famous concurrency book](http://books.google.de/books/about/Java_concurrency_in_practice.html?id=6LpQAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), Goetz suggests that the optimal number of threads in a pool can be calculated using

```
N threads = N CPU * U CPU * (1 + W/C)
```

`W/C` being the waiting-to-computing-ratio. I want to develop a custom [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) which will adjust worker thread quantity using `ThreadPoolExecutor.setCorePoolSize()`, but I do not know how to compute the WC-ratio. Assuming that this [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is the only one used by my application how do I compute that ratio?

Is there a way to track how much time a worker thread is spending on wait/sleep?
Or is there any implementation addressing this problem?

Comment: Note that application workers might change their behaviour, like start waiting for http responses longer or shorter, i want them to adjust dynamically thus tracking each ones W/C over time... like jvisualvm does it...

Comment: isn't Thread.getState() what you need?

Comment: Well i know about getState() but i'm not sure how to use it? shall i query all worker threads for some scheduled time or there is a way to subscribe for state changes... or which ones of those states go under W  i assume both sleeping waiting blocking are... thus i need some advise on this...

Comment: IF you see in visualvm it can track all runing time, waiting time parking time etc... not sure how exactly i do that with only getState... I think there is jmx involved here...

Comment: As of now I don't know any other method than just checking thread states in a loop. I will try to research it because it is interesting.

Comment: I think it will come down to implementing custom Executor which will track its threads states... i wonder why such thing isnt out there yet... cos obviously concurrency is not used properly in most cases...

Comment: What comes to mind as a quick and possibly no-good solution is having wait() methods wrapped so that when any thread calls that wrapped method it would also signal the start of wait state to a subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html

this class contains methods like

`getBlockedCount()`

Returns the total number of times that the thread associated with this ThreadInfo blocked to enter or reenter a monitor.

`getBlockedTime()`

Returns the approximate accumulated elapsed time (in milliseconds) that the thread associated with this ThreadInfo has blocked to enter or reenter a monitor since thread contention monitoring is enabled.

Comment: so i need to get JMX bean and start monitoring my threads? is that the answer?

Comment: The way i understand the situation, is that i'll need to run a separate scheduled task, which will use thread mxbean to collect thread information and start adjusting my thread pool

Comment: Putting this here to find later http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/java_tip_how_list_and_find_threads_and_thread_groups